# ng-repeat show multiple textareas with only one item from list in each

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

I am trying to have a textarea the prints out a list using ng-repeat.  Instead I have several textareas with one item each in the list.  I understand why it is not working, but cannot figure out what to change to get the result I want.  Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app = 'app'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src = 'bower_components/angular/angular.js'>
  </script>
  <script>
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    //printController will show the current $scope
    $scope.list = []
    $scope.submit = function(){
      console.log($scope.myModel)
      if($scope.myModel){
        $scope.list.push(this.myModel);
        $scope.myModel = ''
      }
    }
  }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller = "myController" id = "myController">
      <label>Favorite Food </label>
      <input type="text" ng-model = 'myModel'>
       <button ng-click="submit()">
        <label>Favorite Food:</label>
       </button>
      <div id ='model' ng-if = "myModel">
        <label>Currently Typing: </label>
        <span ng-bind='myModel'>
        </span>  
      </div>
      <textarea ng-repeat="elements in list">{{elements}}</textarea>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I am getting
[image]

This is what I am trying to get

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you have a `ng-repeat` in your `textarea` you will have multiple text-areas, what's the problem? Can you be more specific? Or even provide a plnkr with all the **relevant** code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run my snippet to achieve your goal.

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    //printController will show the current $scope
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.submit = function(){
      console.log($scope.myModel)
      if($scope.myModel){
        $scope.list.push($scope.myModel);
        $scope.myModel = '';
      }
    }
    $scope.$watch(
    function(){return $scope.list.join("\n");},
      function(newVal,oldVal){
        $scope.allTexts = newVal;
      }
    
    );
    
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller = "myController" id = "myController">
      <label>Favorite Food </label>
      <input type="text" ng-model = 'myModel'>
       <button ng-click="submit()">
        <label>Favorite Food:</label>
       </button>
      <div id ='model' ng-if = "myModel">
        <label>Currently Typing: </label>
        <span ng-bind='myModel'>
        </span>  
      </div>
      <textarea ng-model="allTexts"></textarea>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to have a function in the controller that returns the array joined by a newline.

```
$scope.textAreaValues = function(){
  return $scope.list.join('\n');
}
```

Then call this in the HTML template

```
<textarea>{{ textAreaValues() }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use `ng-repeat` like that because it creates instances of the element that you add it to. However, you can achieve what you're after by using a filter:

```
.filter("displayFilter", function(){
    return function(items){
        var result = '';
        angular.forEach(items, function(item, index){
            result += item;
            // only add a newline if we have more items to add
            if(index !== items.length - 1){
                result += '\n';
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
})
```

Then use that filter in your textarea:

```
<textarea>{{elements | displayFilter}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly. You want your list of items to print in the textarea. You should change the following piece of code from

```
<textarea ng-repeat="elements in list">{{elements}}</textarea>
```

to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="list" ng-disabled="true"></input>
```

Do not try to create a textarea then print the values inside of it, rather, create a textarea(input) and bind it to the model containing your list of items.

I have attached a jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6827/